# Pass dropdown selection to "item_name"

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I have looked at some examples on here on how to pass dropdown selection to the "item_name" for my paypal button but just cant get it to work. I don't get any errors. When it goes to the paypal checkout, it should "Application for: Option1" taken from the dropdown selection. Right now it is blank.

Below is the current script that works will for me except the issue above. Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function updateitemname(){
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("membership");
        var selection = dropdown.value;
        console.log(selection);
        var item_name = document.getElementById("item_name");
        item_name.value = selection;
      }

function func(){
        var dropdown = document.getElementById("membership");
        var selection = dropdown.value;
        console.log(selection);
        var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
        amount.value = selection;
      }
        
function UpdateForm (obj1) { 

var themessage = "You are required to complete the following fields: ";

if (obj1.amount.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - Amount";
}

if (obj1.firstname.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - First Name";
}

if (obj1.lastname.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - Last Name";
}

if (obj1.address1.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - Address";
}

if (obj1.city.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - City";
}

if (obj1.state.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - state";
}

if (obj1.zip.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - Zip";
}

//alert if fields are empty and cancel form submit
if (themessage == "You are required to complete the following fields: ") {
obj1.submit();
}
else {
alert(themessage);
return false;
   }


 obj1.item_name.value = "Application for: " + obj1.item_name.value;
 obj1.os0.value = obj1.firstname.value + " " + obj1.lastname.value + " Address: " + obj1.address1.value +  " " + obj1.address2.value + ", " + obj1.city.value + ", " + obj1.state.value +  " " + obj1.zip.value; // + obj1.myopt4.value + ...
 obj1.os1.value = obj1.class_year.value;
}

</script>

<!-- content -->
        <form method="post" name="donationform" id="donationform" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/" onsubmit="this.target='paypal'; return UpdateForm(this);">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="sb-fzhc018066100@business.example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<table width="550" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tr>
  <td width="122">Membership:</td>
  <td width="268">
    <select id="membership" onchange="func()"; "updateitemname()">
        <option selected="selected"></option>
            <option value="10.00">Option1 $10.00 USD</option>
            <option value="100.00">Option2 $100.00 USD</option>
         </select></td>
<td width="168"><input name="amount" type="text" id="amount" maxlength="6" /></td>  
</tr>

<!--<tr>
<td>For:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="item_name" size="38" value=""></td>
</tr>
 --><tr>
  <td>First Name:</td>
  <td><input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" size="38" value="" ></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Last Name :</td><td><input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" size="38" value="" ></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address 1 :</td><td><input name="address1" type="text" id="address1"  size="38" value="" ></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Address 2 :</td><td><input name="address2" type="text" id="address2"  size="38"></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>City:</td><td><input name="city" type="text" size="38"  id="city" value="" ></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>State:</td><td><input name="state" type="text" size="38"  id="state" value="" ></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Zip:</td><td><input name="zip" type="text" size="38"  id="zip" value="" ></td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</table>    

<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="item_name" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Member">
<input type="hidden" name="os0" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF">
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Class Year">
<input type="hidden" name="os1" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<br /><br />
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: It looks like you have already done `obj1.submit` or `return false` before the code to change item_name happens.  What if you put the code to change item_name before that part?

Comment: I got it to work, but it is referencing the 10.00 instead of the label "Option1"

Comment: 10.00 is the value of the select, but Option1 isn't.  You'll have to find `obj1.item_name.options[obj1.item_name.selectedIndex].innerText` to get option1.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I just can't figure this out. Where should I place the script you suggest?